# Django Admin: using different templates for two admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I've a Django project with two different admin-site (as described in [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf) )

I would like to have different custom template for each of them.
I know how to override custom template, by putting html files in myproject/templates/admin/ directory.
However, both admin-site use those templates !

I don't understand how to specify another set of custom templates.

Ideally, I would like having:

```
# For first admin site
myproject/templates/admin-a/
   base.html
   base_site.html
```

and:

```
# For second admin site
myproject/templates/admin-b/
   base.html
   base_site.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first option will be to have two `ModelAdmin` classes, one derived from second one, with some additional parameters defining templates, here is part of the admin code:

```
# Custom templates (designed to be over-ridden in subclasses)
add_form_template = None
change_form_template = None
change_list_template = None
delete_confirmation_template = None
delete_selected_confirmation_template = None
object_history_template = None
```

above variables can be set in your admin class.

second way is to pass a base template name into the template, and then use this (variable) as a parameter to the `extends` template tag. [Documentation here.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#extends)

third option wil be to have a two instances of code running, but with two configs with different setting variable `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, first one e.g.:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('templates-a',)
```

second

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('template-b', 'template-a')
```

Having both template dirs here gives you an *fallback* option, so you will define only those templates which are different.

Third option is easiest to implement (no change to the code) but it requires 2 separated instances working at the same time (more system resources consumed).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the different options, but the first one seems the most easily to implement.

However, in all provided admin templates, there is the "admin/" path hard-coded. I suppose I'll have to copy and override all of them. Maybe using variable in template name could be a good idea