# Multiple admin site with different base_site.html

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to have multiple admin sites with different base templates for each site.

I can create `admin/base_site.html` and add that path to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in the front so that the `base_site.html` takes precedence.

But it overrides the multiple admin sites.

Is there a way to customize each admin site?

I found the same question asked here..
[Django Admin: using different templates for two admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420990/django-admin-using-different-templates-for-two-admin-site)

Wonder if there's a better answer since the question was like 5 years ago.

Comment: Have you added {% extends "base_site.html" %} on top of your template?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer.

request.current_app has the admin site's name which you provided when you instantiated `CustomAdminSite(name='my_admin')

`request.current_app` is `my_admin` so you can branch in base_site.html